# Settling velocity of a particle in a Bingham fluid

Tags: fluid-dynamics, drag, viscosity, non-newtonian-fluids

I am trying to calculate the settling rates of a particle (xenolith) in magma in order to infer the magma ascent velocity. Assuming the fluid is Newtonian, this can simply be worked out using Stokes Law:

$$V = \frac {2 g r^{2} {(p_{s} - p_{l})}}{9 n} .\tag{1} \label{1} $$

Densities and viscosities of the magma can easily by acquired in order to calculate this. However, magma is a [Bingham fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bingham_plastic), so Stokes Law is not accurate. I’m struggling to derive an equation to calculate settling velocities for such liquids. Does anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: It would probably have to be done numerically because of the non-linearity of the viscosity vs shear rate relationship.